# Mootools Request.JSON not liking my accessing an URL pointing to the same machine?

Tags: php, json, mootools

So my js file used to work great:

```
function checkLoggedIn() {
   new Request.JSON({
     url: 'http://localhost/site/ajax/auth.php',
     onSuccess: function(data) {
     // Do some stuff
     }
   }).send('action=check');
}
```

Then I decided to serve my page to the rest of the world, so I changed the code thusly:

```
function checkLoggedIn() {
  new Request.JSON({
  url: '<?=SOME_URL=>ajax/auth.php',
  onSuccess: function(data) {
    // Do some stuff
  }
 }).send('action=check');
}
```

Where in PHP, I've defined SOME_URL to point to the web server. I tried to test the site on the same machine (the web server), but imagine my surprise when it wouldn't work! The request just failed, although I have no idea how to check what error message there is. My js console is empty.

What's weird is if I replace the URL with a relative path, it works fine.

I tried accessing the web server on another computer, with the second code snippet, and it works great. Is the js parser on the server's browser (firefox) not liking the request pointing to itself? Why does it prefer "http://localhost/" over the FQDN?

Thanks!

Edit: For those wondering what the source shows:

```
function checkLoggedIn() {
  new Request.JSON({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/application/ajax/auth.php',
    onSuccess: function(data) {
     // Do some stuff
    }
  }).send('action=check');
}
```

The machine itself is example.com, defined as such on the machine and through apache confs.

Comment: Please give the exact public URL, and then the value of `SOME_URL` (confirm with View Source).  Most likely, the absolute URL is not exactly equivalent.

Comment: Have you canceled out the possibility that this is a cross-domain AJAX issue? http://www.jimbojw.com/wiki/index.php?title=Introduction_to_Cross-Domain_Ajax

Comment: Hi Matthew - for privacy reasons, I'd rather not post the public URL, but they are equivalent. Indeed, I have checked by looking at the source code - thanks for the tip, though!

Comment: stillstanding, the cross-domain violation was an issue I thought of, but I don't believe there is a violation - I am accessing the web site via the public URL, and the ajax URL, in the source, is of the same domain. I double-checked my apache virtual host, and local hostname, both of which match as well. *sigh*.

Comment: Don't show PHP and JavaScript in the same script... show us what happens when you View Source the PHP-generated JS. Change to "example.com" if you don't want your domain known.

Comment: What it says in apache and local hostname is irrelevant. The only thing that matters is what's in the URL-bar in your browser that loads the page - that domain must match exactly that of your ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you use /ajax/auth.php instead of 'http://www.example.com/application/ajax/auth.php'? This should work if they are on the same domain

Comment: it ended up being a cross domain ajax issue. "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" aren't the same, after all :)